# Insert page numbers in OpenXML document using C#

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk

Where can I obtain C# sample code for the Open XML SDK Library?

Comment: What kind of documents? What have you tried?

Comment: Sorry, 'Word' document

Comment: The following thread contains two links with good examples of inserting page numbers: [http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/39713af1-1737-4582-aeed-c88a6626e30a/insert-page-numbers-in-openxml-document-using-c#39713af1-1737-4582-aeed-c88a6626e30a](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/39713af1-1737-4582-aeed-c88a6626e30a/insert-page-numbers-in-openxml-document-using-c#39713af1-1737-4582-aeed-c88a6626e30a)

Answer (score 3):

Using Word, create two documents -- one that does not contain page numbers, and one that is exactly the same but *does* contain page numbers how you want to see them.

Download the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool -- http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425 . This tool can show you exactly the C# code that you need to produce any supplied Office document.

Use the Productivity Tool to open the two documents. Compare and contrast to find the solution that you need.